# Android youtube data player API error

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-5.0-lollipop, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

After integrating youtube api to my application, the application works completely fine in non-lollipop devices. But when i run the application in `Note 3 (lollipop OS)` then application unfortunately stops throwing following error.

**My YoutubeVideo activity:**

```
    public class YoutubeVideo extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    // YouTube player view
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
    MovieActivity ma = new MovieActivity();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("LOG", "Inside Youtube Act1");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.youtube_activity);
            Log.i("LOG", "Inside Youtube Act2"); //this wont execute as an exception is thrown
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("LOG", "Inside Youtube Act3");//this is executed
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("LOG", e.getMessage());

        }

        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        Log.i("LOG", "Inside Youtube Act4");
        Toast.makeText(YoutubeVideo.this, "Loading Video...Please wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Initializing video player with developer key
        youTubeView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        Log.i("LOG", "Inside Youtube Act5");

    }



    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        Log.i("LOG", "Inside YOutube Act7");
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format(
                    getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        Log.i("LOG", "Inside YOutube Act6");
        if (!wasRestored) {

            // loadVideo() will auto play video
            // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
            player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
            player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

            player.loadVideo(Config.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);
            player.setFullscreen(true);
            // Hiding player controls
            player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
        }
    }

    private PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new PlaybackEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {

        }

    };

    private PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new PlayerStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {

                finish();

        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }

}
```

I followed tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/

I dont know why i get error when i click on play button in Note 3 which has lollipop.In all other non-lollipop devices application works completely fine.

**My xml file:**

```
    <RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".YoutubeVideo"
    >

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Android manifest file:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing"
        android:name=".YoutubeVideo"
        android:label="YoutubeVideo"
       >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.andyapps.tnow.YOUTUBEVIDEO" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Errorlog:**

```
02-14 10:07:05.593  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
02-14 10:07:05.593  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at      android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
02-14 10:07:05.593  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
02-14 10:07:05.593  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
02-14 10:07:05.593  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
02-14 10:07:05.593  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
02-14 10:07:05.593  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
02-14 10:07:05.593  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.transition.Scene.enter(Scene.java:175)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.transitionTo(PhoneWindow.java:483)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:426)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at com.andyapps.thetrailersnow.YoutubeVideo.onCreate(YoutubeVideo.java:43)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
02-14 10:07:05.598  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
02-14 10:07:05.603  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ ... 23 more
02-14 10:07:05.603  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
02-14 10:07:05.603  19231-19231/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
02-14 10:43:52.478  24585-24585/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
02-14 10:43:52.478  24585-24585/com.andyapps.tnow W/System.err﹕ ... 26 more
```

Comment: please fix your error log

Comment: Yeah Thank you.i have fixed it.